# How can I input two vector and output a predicted matrix through deep learning

Tags: python-3.x, deep-learning, neural-network

I  want to build a neural network.The input are tow vectors,one is 1×2048 and another is 1×91.The output is a matrix 2048×91.

I try and but I failed in inputing data.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (using pytorch framework):

```
import torch

class MergeModel(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MergeModel, self).__init__()
        self.full_connected_01 = torch.nn.Linear(2048 + 91, 1024)
        self.full_connected_01 = torch.nn.Linear(1024, 2048 * 91)

    def forward(self, first_tensor, second_tensor):
        # You first concatenate your two tensors
        cat_tensor = torch.cat((first_tensor, second_tensor), dim=1)
        
        # And then go through the layers (feel free to change the layers definitions)
        cat_tensor = torch.nn.functional.relu(self.full_connected_01 (cat_tensor ))
        cat_tensor = torch.nn.functional.relu(self.full_connected_01 (cat_tensor ))
        cat_tensor = cat_tensor.view(-1, 2048, 91)
        return cat_tensor

model = MergeModel()
results = model(x1, x2)
```

But without knowing your model architecture and how you want to merge your two input tensors, that might not be a good solution.